# jQuery - Display text when hovered on through `for` loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making a webpage and I am adding a feature; when you hover on a certain `div` another div will display a certain text. There are 5 elements I want to be able to hover and display text.

I added this feature but it did not work properly - only the last hoverable `div` displayed the text. I isolated the elements used and moved them to a sandbox to tweak them. No matter what I do (I got it to work by using a bunch of `if` statements, but I am trying to remove that so it looks neater), only the last `div` will display the text.

Here is a fiddle of the working version with the many `if` statements:
https://codepen.io/SynergyOfLife/pen/qBNJboR

```js
setInterval(function(){
    var dataArray = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
    var isHovered1 = $(`.${dataArray[0]}`).is(":hover");
    var isHovered2 = $(`.${dataArray[1]}`).is(":hover");
    var isHovered3 = $(`.${dataArray[2]}`).is(":hover");
    var isHovered4 = $(`.${dataArray[3]}`).is(":hover");
    var isHovered5 = $(`.${dataArray[4]}`).is(":hover");


    if (isHovered1) {
        $('p').html("TEST")     
    } else if (isHovered2) {
        $('p').html("TEST")
    }else if (isHovered3) {
        $('p').html("TEST")
    } else if (isHovered4) {
        $('p').html("TEST")
    }else if (isHovered5) {
        $('p').html("TEST")
    } else {
        $('p').html("")
    }
    

}, 300);
```

```css
div {
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}

.viewer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="2">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="3">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="4">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="5">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="viewer">
        <p></p>
    </div>
```

Here is the version I am trying to perfect:
https://codepen.io/SynergyOfLife/pen/VwjELME

```js
setInterval(function(){
    var dataArray = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        var isHovered = $(`.${dataArray[i]}`).is(":hover");
        if (isHovered) {
            $('p').html("TEST")
        } else {
            $('p').html("")
        }

    }


    

}, 300);
```

```css
div {
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}

.viewer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="2">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="3">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="4">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="5">
        <a>Only working div?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="viewer">
        <p></p>
    </div>
```

In summary, I am asking for help on how to shorten the number of `if` statements

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't need to go off site just to review your initial issue. Demos are great, but only as support for what actually exists in the question itself. If you click on `<>` in question editor you can even make a  stack snippet that runs right here in the page

Comment: Please let me know if I was not clear in what I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method which accepts two functions, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave.

```js
var dataArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var selectors = '.' + dataArray.join(',.');

$(selectors).hover(function() {
  // `this` is the element the event occurred on
  $('p').html('TEST ' + this.className)
}, function() {
  $('p').empty()
})
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.viewer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
  <a>Test</a>
</div>
<div class="2">
  <a>Test</a>
</div>
<div class="3">
  <a>Test</a>
</div>
<div class="4">
  <a>Test</a>
</div>
<div class="5">
  <a>Test</a>
</div>
<div class="viewer">
  <p></p>
</div>
```